# TYPO3 Memcached clone and upgrade to typo3 6.2

Tags: memcached, typo3

I have a question that I haven't been able to google the answer for about memcached. 
If I have enabled mencached in TYPO3
CLONE a TYPO3 installation(data and files) to a new server.
Upgrade the new cloned installation from 4.7 to 6.2.x
Keep them both running, using the same memcached server. 
Will I run into collisions with the memcached keys or other problems related to memcached?

Thanks for taking some time to answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. As noted on the [wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/Caching_framework#t3lib_cache_backend_MemcachedBackend) there is no namespacing, neither by memcache nor by TYPO3 (which could e.g. just add some prefix). So when using two TYPO3 instances in the same memcache instance, it is possible (and even likely) that the identifiers (e.g. for the cached version of a certain page id) will collide and your production installation might return cached content that your development installation created (have fun debugging this ;-)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer StephenKing. That was just what i neede to know